# Network kernel command line (ip=) doesn't set the ip or route in Ubuntu 18 on Firecracker

Tags: kernel, kernel-parameters

I'm trying to launch a Firecracker VM with Ubuntu and set up networking. If I launch it regularly (taken from [this repo](https://github.com/bkleiner/ubuntu-firecracker)):

```
./firectl --kernel=vmlinux  --root-drive=image.ext4 --firecracker-binary=./firecracker --tap-device=fc_tap0/aa:84:33:ef:da:60 --kernel-opts="init=/bin/systemd noapic reboot=k panic=1 pci=off nomodules console=ttyS0"
```

The vm is launched, then I run:

```
ip addr add 192.168.100.2/24 dev eth0
ip link set eth0 up
ip route add default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth0
echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 > /etc/resolv.conf
```

And I have internet and name solving. ip addr shows:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:84:33:ef:da:60 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.2/24 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a884:33ff:feef:da60/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Now I'm trying to replicate this but without having to run commands on the guest, which makes sense.

Following the [documentation in the kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/nfs/nfsroot.txt), this should work:

```
 ./firectl --kernel=vmlinux  --root-drive=image.ext4 --firecracker-binary=./firecracker --tap-device=fc_tap0/aa:84:33:ef:da:60 --kernel-opts="init=/bin/systemd noapic reboot=k panic=1 pci=off nomodules console=ttyS0 ip=192.168.100.2::192.168.100.1:255.255.255.0:fc:eth0:off:8.8.8.8:8.8.4.4:"
```

With the important part being:

```
ip=192.168.100.2::192.168.100.1:255.255.255.0:fc:eth0:off:8.8.8.8:8.8.4.4:
```

But when it boots, ip addr shows:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether aa:84:33:ef:da:60 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::a884:33ff:feef:da60/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Any attempt to access the network returns `connect: Network is unreachable`, and I have to run the script anyway, otherwise I don't have networking.  What am I doing wrong? Everything I read about this command says ipv6 is not supported, yet it seems that's what it's doing.